# How to hide a Panel inside JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing

I want to hide a JPanel inside a JTabbedPane.

How do I hide the RegPanel? Only to be visible after logging in LogPanel.

```java
JPanel LogPanel = new JPanel();
tabbedPane.addTab("Log in", null, LogPanel, null);
LogPanel.setLayout(null);

JPanel RegPanel = new JPanel();
tabbedPane.addTab("Register Tab", null, RegPanel, null);
RegPanel.setLayout(null);
```

[image]

I tried using setVisible, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: 1. Use a CardLayout, and in the class where you control this layout, not allow it to be shown unless the user has the required credentials. 2. Never, ***NEVER*** use a null layout, as you're doing.

Comment: What do you mean "hide the RegPanel"? Do you want the tab to go away? Or you want the tab to display an empty panel?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the tab that you want to "hide" using `removeTabAt` method from `JTabbedPane`. Changing the state of the `JPanel` that is acting as the tab content pane will not work.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Prof. Dr. David Buzatto
 */
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private JButton closeTabButton;
    private JButton showTabButton;
    private JPanel buttonContainerPanel;
    private JPanel logPanel;
    private JPanel regPanel;
    
    public MainWindow() {
        
        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        closeTabButton = new JButton( "Close Register Tab" );
        showTabButton = new JButton( "Show Register Tab" );
        buttonContainerPanel = new JPanel();
        
        logPanel = new JPanel();
        regPanel = new JPanel();
        
        tabbedPane.addTab( "Log in", logPanel );
        tabbedPane.addTab( "Register Tab", regPanel );
        
        closeTabButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
                try {
                    tabbedPane.removeTabAt( 1 );
                } catch ( IndexOutOfBoundsException exc ) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( 
                            ( (JButton) e.getSource() ).getParent().getParent(), 
                            "There ins't a tab in the index 1.");
                }
            }
        });
        
        showTabButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
                tabbedPane.addTab( "Register Tab", regPanel );
            }
        });
        
        buttonContainerPanel.add( closeTabButton );
        buttonContainerPanel.add( showTabButton );
        
        add( buttonContainerPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH );
        add( tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        setTitle( "JTabbedPane Example" );
        setSize( 600, 600 );
        setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        
    }
    
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainWindow().setVisible( true );
            }
        });
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setVisible, but not on the panel you you add to the tabbed pane. The tabbed pane actually uses setVisible on the components added to it. So if you say "setVisible(false);" when you click on the tab the component will be shown.

The example below shows this behavior. When you select the tab, the visibility of JPanel a gets set. The visibility of `toggle` doesn't get set because it is a child of `a`.

That way calling `toggle.setVisible(false);` it will be hidden when the tab is selected.

For your example,

```
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
wrapper.add(regPanel);
tabbedPane.addTab("Register Tab", null, wrapper, null);
```

That way you can call `setVisible` on the `regPanel` and it will stay hidden when the tab is selected.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class TabMeNot{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JPanel a = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            public void setVisible(boolean t){
                super.setVisible(t);
                System.out.println("set visibility");
            }
        };
        //a.add(new JLabel("A panel"));
        JPanel toggle = new JPanel();
        toggle.add(new JLabel("A panel"));
        a.add(toggle);
        JPanel b = new JPanel();
        b.add(new JLabel("B panel"));
        
        
        
        JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
        tabs.add("A", a);
        tabs.add("B", b);
        JFrame frame= new JFrame("tab me, tab me not");
        frame.setContentPane(tabs);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Timer t = new Timer(2500, evt ->{
            toggle.setVisible(!toggle.isVisible());
        });
        t.start();
    }

}
```